# How to display multiple images in a grid column in GWT GXT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using an IconRenderer to display my images in a grid column. However, based on user search results, I want to display 1 or more icons in the same column of the grid. For example, if the result low has an urgent flag, etc. I am using GridCellRenderer class to render one image already, but need help in how to display multiple. Thanks for reading and helping.

Murad.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of GXT are you using?
If you're in 2.X version - Refer [Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260141-Image-within-Grid-cell)
If you're in 3.X version - create a custom cell that renders image(AbstractSafeHtmlCell). Add multiple icons in that cell using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

From GXT 4 with GWT 2.7, assuming you defined a grid column and configured bindings so that you presently display a String value that you will want to display as different images instead of strings, the bits of code below illustrate a native String display versus one rendering images.

This is your grid Row model, typically bound to a REST/JSON data source, here with 'id' and 'myVal' attributes; we build a relative URL path to the image resources, here "images/*.png", in an model property:

```
public class MyRowModel extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected MyRowModel() {
  }
  // what makes a unique ID for GWT/GXT grid entries, not necessarily displayed
  public final native String getId()       /*-{return this.id;}-*/;
  public final native String getMyStringVal() /*-{return this.myVal;}-*/;
  public final native String getMyImagePath()  /*-{return "images/" + this.myVal + ".png";}-*/;
  ... more model properties
}
```

Then, in you child Widget class where you build your grid, you likely have declared your binding (grid access to row model), followed by the creation of the grid that you'll later put in a layout:

```
public class MyPanel extends Widget implements IsWidget {
  protected com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore<MyRowModel> store;

  interface MyGridRow extends com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.PropertyAccess<MyRowModel> {
    @Editor.Path("id")
    ModelKeyProvider<MyRowModel> key(); // unique key for each row, here mapped to 'id'
    ValueProvider<MyRowModel, String> myStringVal();
    ValueProvider<MyRowModel, String> myImagePath();
    ... more bindings...
  }

  private static final MyGridRow myRow = GWT.create(MyGridRow.class);

  com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.Grid<MyRowModel> createGrid() {
    IdentityValueProvider<MyRowModel> identityValueProvider = new IdentityValueProvider<>();
    ColumnConfig<MyRowModel, String> stringColumn = new ColumnConfig<>(myRow.myStringVal(), 50, "Text");
    ColumnConfig<MyRowModel, String> imageColumn = new ColumnConfig<>(myRow.myImagePath(), 50, "Image");
    ... more column configs ...
    List<ColumnConfig<MyRowModel, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add(stringColumn);
    columns.add(imageColumn);
    imageColumn.setCell(new ImageCell()); // the trick is here!
    ...
    final com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.Grid<MyRowModel> grid = new Grid<>(store, new ColumnModel<>(columns), new GridView<MyRowModel>(new Css3GridAppearance()));
    ... add sorting, filters, coloring to your grid
    return grid;
  }

  ... more logic to layout the created grid ...
}
```